# SSH permission denied : using paramiko module inside my flask app and deployed same using mod_wsgi(Apache) mode

Tags: python, ssh, flask, mod-wsgi, paramiko

**Config file(PetInit.conf):**

```html
   

WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi  
<VirtualHost *:80>  
ServerName xx.xx.xx.xxx  
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/PetInit/PetInit.wsgi  
WSGIDaemonProcess PetInit group=root threads=5 home=/usr/share

<Directory /usr/share/PetInit>
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIProcessGroup PetInit
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi file(PetInit.wsgi):**

```
 import sys  
    import logging  
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr) 
    sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages") 
    sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PetInit")  
    from PetInitServer import app as application
```

**app(server) code:**

```
import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient  
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()    
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())     
ssh.connect(remotenodeip,username='root', password='*****',key_filename='/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')
```

**Server logs:**

> 

```
[Tue Oct 03 05:39:45 2017] [error]     ssh.connect(ip,username='root', password='*****',key_filename='/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')  
[Tue Oct 03 05:39:45 2017] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 290, in connect  
[Tue Oct 03 05:39:45 2017] [error]     sock.connect(addr)  
[Tue Oct 03 05:39:45 2017] [error]   File "<string>", line 1, in connect  
[Tue Oct 03 05:39:45 2017] [error] error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

**Note :**
If i start my flask app on port 5000 ( without mod_wsgi) , there is no problem in ssh.  So i suspect the Wsgidaemon process does not have permission. how to give permission to wsgidaemon process or any other way to resolve this issue ??

Comment: Maybe if you tell us which OS you are exactly on and why you are still using the old version 2.6 of Python.

Comment: I am using Redhat Linux 6.4 and python version is default comes with our software.

Comment: You are talking about "Redhat Enterprise Linux"? "Redhat Linux" was discontinued 14 years ago.

Comment: yes . Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

Comment: As a starting point I'd recommend moving to Python 3.x if the only reason you're using the old version is that it's "in the box"

Comment: @BrettJ : As you suggested i have upgraded python version to 2.7.11 still same issue. Here I want to highlight that problem is related to WSGI daemon process as everything works fine in case i use curl command.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but wouldn't you want to create a new group and then add the daemon to that group. You would then make the group the owner of the directory you're attempting to access with chmod 770? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code under Apache will run as a special Apache user, it wouldn't normally have access to the file `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Also, as the `/root/.ssh` directory is only accessible to the user `root` and not usually via group access setting `group` for `WSGIDaemonProcess` to `root` may not be enough. Run:

```
ls -lasd /root/.ssh
```

and check the directory permissions. If it is something like:

```
 0 drwx------  11 root  root   374 28 Aug 13:02 .
```

then is not accessible via group.

You shouldn't necessarily add group access though as I think tools will then not accept stuff in it as they may validate permissions.

Since it is only the public key, and not the private, then you could just copy it to a place where is accessible.

You may want to run the daemon mode process group as a completely new user though and not Apache user, with only that new user able to access the public key.

Comment: this might be one of the problem . but in my case i given all the permission to directory.

Comment: Then it could well be a SELinux permissions issue. The SELinux profile likely prohibits the Apache user access anything under ``/root``.

Comment: I think you can create a group like `admin` and add `root` and `apache` into it, then grant group `r` permission on the key file, its parent and grandparents dir. So `root` owns the file and `apache` can use it.That's how I solved it, at least.

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution and its working fine . httpd_can_network_connect parameter was restricted in my Linux system.

To check "httpd_can_network_connect" value , run the below command:

**/usr/sbin/getsebool -a | grep "httpd_can_network_connect"**

if output is like :

httpd_can_network_connect --> off

then set the value to on.

**setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on**